# Abstract factory pattern and serialization in Java

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, interface

I have an interface A:

```
public interface A {
   ...
}
```

I have a factory interface FA:

```
public interface FA { 
   public A create(); 
   public A deserialize(String pathToFile);
}
```

I want to have **serialize(String pathToFile)** interface method somewhere. And here comes the problem... Simple solution is to put it in A - but it's wrong, because serialization and deserialization logic should be in the same class. But how do I put it in FA? Making it generic seems to be a wrong path (`FA<A>`)

Comment: Yes, in case if it's in FA. Problem is that implementations of FA should know how to serialize "A obj" being passed.

Comment: Why do you think adding a type parameter would be wrong? `FA`  creates, serializes and deserializes `Object`s of the same type, if i understood that part correctly. If you have an interface named `A` however, using a different name for the type parameter would be advisable, since it reduces the chances of confusing the types.

Comment: TRy this public interface FA extends A